# Return distinct rows from not entirely distinct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Two columns, first is distcint, second not so much.

```
Col1 ---- Col2
1    ---- abc
1    ---- abc (123)
2    ---- def
2    ---- def (324)
```

etc

I need to bring back distinct records, but only the ones with the longer Col2.

I've tried using the CONTAINS function, but my table isn't full-text indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use use `ROW_NUMBER()` ordering by the `LEN()` of Col2:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Col1, Col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY LEN(Col2) DESC) rn
    FROM YourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0852/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  col1 ,
        col2
FROM    ( SELECT    col1 ,
                    col2 ,
                    Rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2 DESC ) row
          FROM      dbo.table
        ) t
WHERE   row = 1
```

You can also try this ..